# How to load style from postgresql?

Tags: qgis, python, postgresql, style, sld

Is there any way to load a postgresql style for a vector layer using python?
There is a function:
`loadNamedStyleFromDb (const QString &db, const QString &theURI, QString &qml)`.Does it support loading of postgresql styles?

Comment: did you test loadNamedStyle(URI string) method?
reading the code this is the method that dinamically load the loadStyle method from db provider (postgis or spatialite)

Comment: I'll check it.What's the format of uri?like that? `uri=u'dbname=\'dbname\' host=localhost port=5432 user=\'leonidas\' password=\'xxx\' table=\'layer_styles_table_name'\ () sql='`

Comment: sure you can write it down manually, but other way is to set attributes of QgsDataSoruceURI 
http://qgis.org/api/classQgsDataSourceURI.html
and then the .uri() method to get the complete string