# How to load a style from POSTGIS in PyQt

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, layers

The thing is that I have four styles I have created in QGIS through the GUI and saved into a postgresql database.

I can see them in the table named ***layer_styles***

I have seen similar questions asking to load from qml file, or even from a database, [like that](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112773/how-to-load-style-from-postgresql) but it looks as if I need to get a styled layer before for get the style from it.

It's like I say or can I load the styles from database without a styled layer?

Anyway I don't know how must I do to get the styles and use it for another layers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is my try to load a style stored in Postgres database.
QGIS saves the layers in a table called ***layer_styles***
The column I need is ***styleqml***, so I need to make a query like that:

```
select styleqml from public.layer_styles;
```

There are another descriptive columns like *stylename* or *description* I can use for help to choose the properly style. I could do:

```
select stylename, description, styleqml from public.layer_styles;
```

I have used only styleqml column and I have stored all the records in a list

Finnally I only have to set the style in my layer like that:

```
self.vlayer.applyNamedStyle(mylist[n])
```

I show a snippet of my code. Sorry if there are mistakes or if I am saying any silliness, but it works for me:

```
self.loadStyles = QtSql.QSqlQuery(self.conexion)
self.listOfStyles=[]
if self.loadStyles:
    self.loadStyles.exec_("SELECT styleqml FROM public.layer_styles")           
    while self.loadStyles.next():
        self.listOfStyles.append(unicode(self.loadStyles.value(0)))
self.myStyle = self.listOfStyles[1] # 1 in my case      
self.vlayer.applyNamedStyle(self.myStyle)
```