# Load and apply Style from Postgres in QGIS 3

Tags: postgis, vector, style, qgis-3

I want to write a plugin in QGIS3 that changes the style of a vector layer. The styles to be loaded are saved in a postgres database in the table 'layer_styles'.

I read [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233620/display-value-relation-qgis) or [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156359/how-to-load-a-style-from-postgis-in-pyqt) , to use `applyNamedStyle()` which is not available anymore in QGIS3.

Therefore, I tried using `loadNamedStyle()`:

```
uri=QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("host_name", "5432", "database_name", "user", "xxx")    
uri.setSchema("public")
uri.setSql("SELECT styleqml FROM public.layer_styles WHERE stylename='nice'")
self.layer.loadNamedStyle(uri.uri(False))
```

This doesn't give me an error but nothing happens.

Do I only 'load' the style and not apply it?

My layer is of class `QgsVectorLayer`, could this be the problem?

Is there another way of loading and applying the style to the vector layer?

Answer (score 5):

What happens if you do

```
iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

and/or

```
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(the_layer.id())
```

after your `loadNamedStyle()` ?

The method `applyNamedStyle()` in QGIS2 has been replaced by `importNamedStyle()` in QGIS3, cp. **QGIS API Documentation > Backwards incompatible changes** https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html

`importNamedStyle()` expect a `QDomDocument` as input (https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#a59f50a11ff98460ac9e6c8993bff6295), so assumed you have your `styleqml` (String) selected from the `layer_styles` table you can import the style as follows:

```
from PyQt5.QtXml import QDomDocument
styledoc = QDomDocument()
styledoc.setContent(styleqml) 
the_layer.importNamedStyle(styledoc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clue.

I'm then loading a style from PostGIS like this:

```
uri_prod.setDataSource('public', 'layer_styles', None)
styles = QgsVectorLayer(uri_prod.uri(False), 'layer_styles', "postgres")
styleqml = ""
for style in styles.getFeatures():
    if style['f_table_schema'] == 'my_schema' and style['f_table_name'] == 'my_layer_name':
        styleqml = style['styleqml']

styledoc = QDomDocument()
styledoc.setContent(styleqml)
my_layer.importNamedStyle(styledoc)
```

And my_layer had the style expected.